# how to use session to passing values between page c# ASP.NET web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a newbie in C# web api and I want to pass values between pages by using `Session`.
Here is my code.

**page1.aspx**

```
<asp:Label ID="lb_front" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="bt1" runat="server" OnClick="bt1_Click" />
```

**page1.aspx.cs**

```
protected void bt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lb_front.Text = txt1.Text;
    Session["user"] = txt1.Text;
}
```

**page2.aspx**

```
<asp:Label ID="lb_top" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**page2.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lb_top.Text = "<img src='./Images_top/'"+ Session["user"]+"'.jpg'></img>";
    lb_top.Text += Session["user"];
}
```

I want to use the session value in the path to display an image on the label, but this isn't working.

Comment: Your question is actually "How to set image src programmatically in asp.net?"
So, google that and find answer.

Comment: why not using asp control for your image?

Comment: 1) This is not Web API, it's ASP.NET Forms. Web API is a different product and does not involve GUIs. I find it's a good idea to actually know what tools you are using for the job :-)

Comment: 2) What does "not working" mean? Do the contents of Session["user"] get dumped into the tag as you expect? If so, does that form a valid link to a real image on your server? It seems like you're inserting it into a Label, I suspect (but I've never tried because that's a weird thing to do) there's a good chance it will encode the text and just display the tag, rather than actually interpreting it as HTML? Either use an <asp:LiteralControl to add it to, or use an <asp:Image tag instead.

Comment: page1 post to page2 after you can get txt1 value with Request.Form["txt1"]

Comment: Thank you so much for all of comment. it help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the image path dynamically like:

**page2.aspx**

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="image" />
<asp:Label ID="lb_top" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**page2.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sessionValue = (string)Session["user"];

    image.ImageUrl = "../Images_top/"+ sessionValue +".jpg"; // set image url/src from session

    lb_top.Text += sessionValue;
}
```

Comment: thanks alot it works now ! your code ' string sessionValue' that works perfect for me. .